# Photoshop doesn't save composite previews

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, mac

First: I have Photoshop CS3 running on Mac OS 10.7.2. (This also occurred in 10.6.8.)

In Photoshop preferences, I have every preview-saving option enables in File Handling, yet Quick Looking a file it saves always gives me a "This layered Photoshop file was not saved with a composite image."

Why isn't this working, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under `Preferences > File Handling` make sure that you have "Maximize PSB and PSD file compatibility" set to "Always" or "Ask". That is the setting that determines whether a full resolution composite image is saved with the file.

Comment: That didn't do it.

Comment: Actually, it seems it may have... maybe it just needed some time to think. ;)